# How to change the button background color using jQuery selectors and if else statement?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I need to change btn1 background color from transparent to green when someone click on it. If the user clicks on the button again btn1's background color should be change from green to transparent.
Is this following if condition is valid or not?

```
if(('#btn1').css("background-color")== "green")
```

```
function vote(str){
  
  if(str==1){
        
        if(('#btn1').css("background-color")== "green"){
      
                $('#btn1').css("background-color","");
      
      
        }else{
      
                $('#btn1').css("background-color","green");
      
      }
  
  }else{
  
    $('#btn2').css("background-color","red");
  }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id="btn1" onclick="vote(1)" >Up Vote</button>
<button id="btn2" onclick="vote(2)" >Down Vote</button>
```

Comment: No - you have a typo - missing `$` in your first `if`. I.e.; `if(('#btn` is not the same as `if($('#btn`

Comment: Always check the console for errors (F12) `btn1.css is not a function`

Comment: Also, always check what you're comparing, `console.log($('#btn1').css("background-color"))` - as noted above, in Chrome, = `rgb(239, 239, 239)` (initially) and `rgb(0, 128, 0)` when set to `green`.   https://jsfiddle.net/9qgxuL14/

Answer (score 2):

You can use seperate classes for each color, and then use the `toggleClass` function to change them as required:

```js
$("button").on("click", (e) => {
  $(e.target).toggleClass("transparent green")
})
```

```css
.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.transparent {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="transparent">hello</button>
```

Comment: You only need to use one class and make use of the C part of CSS (but otherwise, yes, classes are the way to go here)

Comment: jQuery also supports an array of classes to toggle. `$(e.target).toggleClass(["transparent", "green"])`;

Comment: @EmielZuurbier don't need an array if they're strings: `$(e.target).toggleClass("transparent green")`  (array is useful if they're variables)

Comment: @freedomn-m even better!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use css to achieve the effect you want, and use the `addClass` and `toggleClass` functions to toggle and add classes.

addClass()

> Adds the specified class(es) to each element in the set of matched
> elements.

toggleClass()

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of
> matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the
> value of the state argument.

### Use css file, use jquery to switch css rules

```js
$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('background-green');
});

$('#btn2').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('background-red');
});
```

```css
.background-red {
  background-color: red !important ;
}

.background-green {
  background-color: green !important;
}

.background-transparent {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="background-transparent">Up Vote</button>
<button id="btn2">Down Vote</button>
```

---

### Instead of using css file, use jquery to create css rules, and switch

```js
$('<style>')
  .prop('type', 'text/css')
  .html("\
    .background-red {\
        background-color: red !important ;\
    }\
    .background-green {\
        background-color: green !important ;\
    }\
    .background-transparent {\
        background-color: transparent ;\
    }")
  .appendTo('head');

$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('background-green');
});

$('#btn2').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('background-red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1" class="background-transparent">Up Vote</button>
<button id="btn2">Down Vote</button>
```

---

### Use jquery to set and switch css properties

```js
// Initialize for button
$('#btn1').css('background-color', 'transparent');

$('#btn1').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 
    $(this).css('background-color') == 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' ? 
    'green' : 'transparent'
  );
});

$('#btn2').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">Up Vote</button>
<button id="btn2">Down Vote</button>
```

Comment: In my case I cannot use toggle classes. Any method without using toggle class?

Comment: @IUKottahchchi I re-edited the answer and added two ways, hope it helps